# Union axiom and creation of natural numbers

Tags: set-theory

i'm studying the axioms of set theory, and I got stuck at  the pair axiom and the union axiom.
The pair axioms states:
"Let A and B be sets. There exists a set S such that $S=\{A,B\}$
The union axiom states:
"Let F be a set whose elements are sets. There exists a set S such that $S=\{x|x∈A$ for some $A∈F\}$

Now: 
We can define $0$ to be the empty set $0=Ø$.
Then we can use the pair axiom to create a singleton, that we define as 1: $1=\{Ø\}$
Then we can use the pair axiom again to create the set, called 2: $2=\{Ø,\{Ø\}\}$.

Now how can I create the set 3?

My book says that I cannot use only the pair axiom to do it, and I understand why, since with that axiom I can only create sets with 2 elements, but how can I create it with the union axiom?

My book only says:
"using the union axiom we take the union over the set $2$" but how? that axiom states that we can take the elements of some sets that are in a bigger set, but where is this bigger set?

If i use the union axiom and pair $1$ and $2$ i can get the set $\{\{Ø\}, \{Ø,\{Ø\}\}\}$ from which i can only take the elements  $Ø$, and {Ø}, but i cannot take the whole $\{Ø,\{Ø\}\}$ (which is $2$) so it wouldn't work anyway since $3$ is defined as $\{0, 1, 2\}$ and i can't obtain the $2$. I'm really confused, could you guys help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Note that for any $n$, $$n+1=n\cup\{n\}$$This means that to form $n+1$, we simply pair $n$ with $n$ to form $\{n\}$, and then pair $n$ with $\{n\}$ to form $\{n,\{n\}\}$, and then take the union of this set to form $n+1$.

Comment: Yeah know and I understand that formula, but I'm trying to understand why I need the union axiom to create the number 3, 4 etc, that is what I dont get

Comment: How would you do it without?